# I downloaded the sdk for google-analytics but where i can setup the account?

Tags: google-analytics

I downloaded the sdk for google-analytics for android but where i can setup the account?
I have the option for only adding http or https wesites.
I use the UA number that i got from a fake url but i get no analytics.
Also..

> Tracking Status:     Tracking Not Installed (Last checked: 19-Jul-2010 11:35:21 ) 
>   The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's homepage. For Analytics to function, you or your web administrator must add the code to each page of your website.

Comment: Didn't know that Google had this for iPhone and Android. I learned something new. :-)

Comment: Btw i found Localytics that support Real-Time logging and has an open source SDK.Really cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Analytics javascript runs when you load a page. You must have a Javascript snippet that actually notifies the Google Analytics server when a client visits the page. This snippet is available once you've set up a site in Google Analytics.

I'm not exactly clear what you mean by "where can I setup the account". It sounds like you've found it.

**Edit:** For the Mobile version (non website) there's info [here](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/):

From that page:

> Before you begin using the SDK, you
>   must first create a free account at
>   www.google.com/analytics and create a
>   new website profile in that account
>   using a fake but descriptive website
>   URL (e.g.
>   http://mymobileapp.mywebsite.com).
>   Once you create the profile, write
>   down or keep a copy of the web
>   property ID that is generated for the
>   newly-created profile.

Comment: i've done that but maybe it needs time to proccess the data. Is there a time line for the first data to show up?

Comment: It does seem to take some time before it will show results -- I'd wait an hour or two. I don't know what the official word is on how long you need to wait.

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall the Google Analytic Mod from your Zen Cart follow these steps http://surreystore.com/Forums/joomla-help/uninstall-google-analytics-by-andrew/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [here](http://www.google.com/analytics/), where it says "Sign up now"? I'm not 100% sure, and am not a user of analytics, but that seemed likely to me. Also see [here](http://www.google.com/analytics/discover_analytics.html) for a getting started guide.